# Parsing of json array with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json array

```
var a_values = new Array();
a_values["AF:All"] = new Array('KBL:Kabul','US:New york');
a_values["AL:All"] = new Array('TIA:Tirana');
```

How can i find , whether a given string is in  a_values, using jquery

for example, i need to check whether 'Kabul' is there , in a_values

Comment: [Don't create arrays like that](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX1). And an Array has only numeric keys; you're looking for [objects](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29). (Careful; that website calls them "JSON", which isn't strictly accurate. [JSON is a format _based on_ this object definition notation that's found in the Javascript language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd like this a little better:

```
var abbreviations = new Array();
abbreviations['AF'] = new Array();
abbreviations['AF']['KBL'] = 'Kabul';
abbreviations['AF']['US'] = 'New York';
abbreviations['AL'] = new Array();
abbreviations['AL']['TIA'] = 'Tirana';
```

Then there are two ways of checking for existence of a string.  One would be:

```
JSON.stringify(abbreviations).indexOf('Kabul') >= 0
```

And another would be to loop through the array with a for loop, looking at each value.

Comment: But the problem is that, the array is a predefined result from  another location

Comment: I see.  That's fine, you can still stringify it with the method I showed.  The loop would be a little nastier but you could do it that way too.  If you're actually getting a JSON string btw, you can just do `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

That's not JSON at all, that's just Javascript. JSON is a text format for representing objects, based on parts of the Javascript syntax.

You are creating an array, but then you are using it as a regular object. (The reason that it works anyway, is that an array is also an object.) You should create an object instead:

```
var a_values = {};
```

To look for a value in the object, you can loop through it's properties:

```
var find = 'Kabul';
var found = false;
$.each(a_values, function(key, value){
  if (value.indexOf(find) != -1) {
    found = true;
    return false; // skip rest of the loop
  }
});
```